# kendoDatePicker knockout binding not working

Tags: knockout.js, data-binding, durandal, kendo-datepicker

I'm trying to bind kendoDatePicker value from my view model.

when i use a simple observable it's perfectly working.
html:

```
<input data-bind="kendoDatePicker: { value: myDate().selectedDate} " />
```

Change Date

```js
var DateModel = function (json) {
            var self = this;

self.selectedDate = ko.observable((!json || !json.Value) ? new Date('01/02/2015') : new Date(json.Value));

};


function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    // initializing  my object with empty string to avoid html databinding exceptions
    self.myDate= ko.observable(new DateModel(''));

    self.changeDate = function () {

    self.myDate(new DateModel({Value:"09/08/1935"}));
    };

    return self;
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<!-- REFERENCES
    http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2012.3.1315/styles/kendo.common.min.css
    http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2012.3.1315/styles/kendo.default.min.css 
    http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2012.3.1315/js/kendo.core.min.js
    http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2012.3.1315/js/kendo.web.min.js
    http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/knockout/knockout-2.2.1.js
    http://rniemeyer.github.com/knockout-kendo/js/knockout-kendo.min.js
-->


<input data-bind="kendoDatePicker: { value: myDate().selectedDate} " />

 <button data-bind="click: changeDate">Change Date</button>
    <p data-bind="text: myDate().selectedDate">  </p>
```

demo : http://jsfiddle.net/NGLEp/27/

But when i use an obsevable model with json values (like i'm parsing my webservice result ) it doesn't work.

```js
var DateModel = function (json) {
            var self = this;

self.selectedDate = ko.observable((!json || !json.Value) ? new Date('01/02/2015') : new Date(json.Value));

};


function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    // initializing  my object with empty string to avoid html databinding exceptions
    self.myDate= ko.observable(new DateModel(''));

    self.changeDate = function () {

    self.myDate().selectedDate(new Date());
    };

    return self;
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<!-- REFERENCES
    http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2012.3.1315/styles/kendo.common.min.css
    http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2012.3.1315/styles/kendo.default.min.css 
    http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2012.3.1315/js/kendo.core.min.js
    http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2012.3.1315/js/kendo.web.min.js
    http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/knockout/knockout-2.2.1.js
    http://rniemeyer.github.com/knockout-kendo/js/knockout-kendo.min.js
-->


<input data-bind="kendoDatePicker: { value: myDate().selectedDate} " />

 <button data-bind="click: changeDate">Change Date</button>
    <p data-bind="text: myDate().selectedDate">  </p>
```

demo : http://jsfiddle.net/NGLEp/26/

help please !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
self.myDate(new DateModel({Value:"09/08/1935"}));
```

overrides your old instance of `selectedDate` that is bounded to the datePicker control. You can use a `setter` method to set the value of originally binded observable.

```
self.setDate = function(json){
    self.selectedDate((!json || !json.Value) ? new Date('01/02/2015') : new Date(json.Value));
};
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/newuserjs/NGLEp/28/